# Can the socket.io client emit events locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, socket.io

Is it possible to use socket.io to dispatch events to the client and not send them to the server? Something like:

```
socket.emitLocally('some event', data);
```

---

**Here is why I'm asking:**

At the moment my server emits events to all sockets.

```
io.sockets.emit()
```

While this works well, there is the possibility of a delay between the user interaction and the response from the server.

This is why I would prefer to use broadcast on the server side and handle things immediatly in the broadcasting client.

```
socket.broadcast.emit()
```

The client is based on angular.js and the modules don't know of each other. I can't access the code that is responsible for updating the client directly. I would have to use some kind of event dispatching service which I would inject into relevant modules.

Since this is basically [what I am doing with socket.io right now](https://github.com/marcorei/lunchpad/blob/master/dev/js/service.socket.js) I wonder if I could not simply use their system to do this.

Thank you for any input or suggestions!

Comment: So, you want a client to send a message to itself and not to anyone else?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, but without actually sending a message (to the server and back). I just want to trigger the event that would be dispatched if a message had been sent to the client. Does this make sense? ;)

Comment: OK, I guess I follow your desire, but I'm not aware of any capability in socket.io to do that.

Comment: Instead of using socket.io in possibly unsupported ways (non standard api can break overtime), it may be better to use events.EventEmitter() instead. All listeners will instead use the eventEmitter.on(), and your emitLocally + actual emit will both call the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done as shown on the socket.io client code on function [Emitter.prototype.emit](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/dist/socket.io.dev.js#L1618).

Events are saved on `socket._callbacks` with the prefix `$`, so for instance `"connected"` would be under `_callbacks` as `"$connected"`.

You can replicate the behaviour of said function by using:

```
// You can use internal (e.g. disconnected) or custom events (e.g. ChatMessage).
var event = "MyEvent";
// Set your args exactly as in your socket.io server emit.
// Note that they will be used on an apply so they must be within an array.
var args = [1, 2, 3];

if(socket._callbacks) { // If the socket has callbacks
    var callbacks = socket._callbacks['$' + event]; // Load the callback event
    if (callbacks) {
        callbacks = callbacks.slice(0);
        for (var i = 0, len = callbacks.length; i < len; ++i)
          callbacks[i].apply(socket, args);
    } // Otherwise no calls
}
```

In the example above the callback for "MyEvent" will be called with the arguments 1, 2, 3.

A further example on how to use this on an actual connection:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on("getSingleUpdate", function(id, data){
        alert("Event #"+id+" data "+data);
    });

    function emitLocalEvent(event/*, arg1, arg2, etc.*/) {
        if(socket._callbacks) { 
            var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
                callbacks = socket._callbacks['$' + event];
            if (callbacks) {
                callbacks = callbacks.slice(0);
                for (var i = 0, len = callbacks.length; i < len; ++i)
                  callbacks[i].apply(socket, args);
            }
        }
    }

    // Emitting fake events
    emitLocalEvent("getSingleUpdate", 1, "Hello");
    emitLocalEvent("getSingleUpdate", 2, "World!");

    // You can even receive an array of events via socket.io...
    socket.on("getMultipleEvents", function(eventArray) {
        for(var i in eventArray)
            emitLocalEvent.apply(null, eventArray[i]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you catch events on the client side using

```
io.on("name",callback);
```

you could just call

```
callback();
```

I hope i could help! =)

Comment: My example was a bit too simple. You are right of course, in a simple example like that I could just call the listeners.
The reason I asked this question though was, that I am using socket.io as a centralized event hub. So I can never be sure what parts of my application will listen to the events it receives. 
Calling all the listeners when emitting an event to the server could get pretty messy and might not even be possible in some cases. So, unfortunately, this does not solve my problem.

Comment: TBH, I don't really understand how you could have a system that receives a message from the server using `io.on` but you don't know what the callback is. Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: I don't know what the callbacks are when using `io.emit`. But I do know which event my client would receive if everything goes well.

For example: an angular application has three completely separate modules: one for displaying a Toast-like notification every time a message has been added, one for listing chatrooms with a count for unread messages on the left side of the screen, and one for listing messages of the selected chat on the right side of the screen. 

(continued in the next comment..)

Comment: (...continued from previous comment...) All of those modules are interested in an event for a new message. All of them listen to `io.on("new message",fn)` to modify their data snapshot which they downloaded at the beginning of their lifecycle. -- For the client sending a new message, I want these changes to be instant (right after the click). But the module which calls `io.emit` to send a new message can't possible know the callbacks of the other modules.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me, but I still do not understand how it is possible that you don't know what the callbacks are. Could you please add a little code example?

Comment: Sure ;) thank you for sticking around! It's an old project -- as is this question, but it still demonstrates well what I was saying above. [This module](https://github.com/marcorei/lunchpad/blob/master/dev/js/controller.view.admin.js#L168) emits an event "create venue". Besides this module, [another module](https://github.com/marcorei/lunchpad/blob/master/dev/js/service.venue.js#L298) also listens to the event "venue create done" which will be emitted by the server to all connected sockets. You see why callback() wouldn't work? (...)

Comment: (...) The first module has no reference to the listener in the second module, and to be honest, there shouldn't be one. I would have cross-dependecies all over the place.