# Python socket.io locally emit an event

Tags: python, events, socket.io

I would like to emit a local event instead of using one from the server. Basically, locally call events. The reason would be is to process data which then can be used by another function.

**Related questions:**

[Can the socket.io client emit events locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324169/can-the-socket-io-client-emit-events-locally) - This only supports node.js and no python implementation of it.

**Code:**

```py
await self.sio.connect(SOCKET_IP, namespaces=['/'], transports=['websocket'])
await sio.emit("connection")
await sio.emit('authentication', {'token': new_token})

@sio.event
async def auth_err(data):
    authErr = True
    await sio.disconnect()

@sio.event
async def alive_status(data):
    await sio.emit("alive_status_return", "alive")

@sio.on('connected')
async def on_connect(data):
    print("Connected")
```

I know for sure `sio.emit()` will broadcast to the server which I do not want.

Looking at doing [`sio.call()`](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=call#socketio.Client.call) but ended up with `await sio.call("on_new_data")` giving `Sending packet MESSAGE data 21["on_new_data"]`

Then the function doesn't get the data

```py
@sio.event
async def on_new_data():
    print("2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to write a custom function within the `asyncio_client.py` of python socket.io for this

```py
    async def _call_event(self, event, namespace, data=None):
        namespace = namespace or '/'
        self.logger.info('Received custom event "%s" [%s]', event, namespace)
        try:
            if data:
                r = await self._trigger_event(event, namespace, data)
            else:
                r = await self._trigger_event(event, namespace)
        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())
```